if deleteusername matches in one of v2_communities then that value needs to be removed from v2_communities
Input:
{ 
  "abc": "123",
  "v2_communities": [
    "community1",
    "community2"
  ],
  "DeleteUserName": "community1"
}

output-
{ 
  "abc": "123",
  "v2_communities": [
    "community2"
  ]
}

v2 communities community 1 needs to be deleted as the input has the value community1 for the key deleteusername.

You can use the following shift transformation spec :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "abc": "&",
      "v2_communities": {
        "*": { // the layer for the indexes of the array
          "*": { // the layer for the values of the array
            "@3,DeleteUserName": { // bring the value after 3 levels
              // traversing the branches of tree
              "&": { // copy value of DeleteUserName just from one outer level 
                // in this case element's value of array matches with 
                // the value of DeleteUserName
                "": "" // removes the matched element
              },
              "*": { // keep the other elements
                "@(5,&4[&3])": "&5[]" // &3 targets values
                                      // &4 targets indexes of the outermost array
                                      // 5 and &5 target that array itself 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

